# Format a document using styles with macro

Tags: microsoft-word, vba

I have a document where I have created some styles. The content in this document is manually tagged. That is, where Heading 1 is to be applied it is tagged as H1 and the same way for Heading 2, Heading 3 and so on.

How would I create a macro for automatically formatting this document? The macro has to read the tag and apply the corresponding style.

Comment: Could you clarify how each paragraph is "tagged". Is there a text prefix like "H1" added to the beginning of each paragraph?

Answer (score 1):

[The Find command in VBA will do what you want](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa211953%28v=office.11%29.aspx). Use it with the Replacement object to change the formatting of the found object.

To do this for the whole document, you need to start with a reference to the ActiveDocument.Content object and create a [Find loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10820184/ms-word-macro-find-all-method) until Find returns no further objects.